# WYSIWYG - Keep textarea selection selected after surrounding it in tags?

Tags: javascript, textarea, textselection

**Edit:** Just as I posted this I found a piece of code that does it easily. :D

[This post](http://technology.hostei.com/?p=3) has a jQuery solution that works perfectly for me.

---

I have a script that adds BBCode tags around the selected text in a textarea when the user clicks on a button, After clicking the button, the tags are added, I re-gain focus on the text-area using `textarea.focus()` but while the text has moved due to the added tags, the text selection is at the same position as before adding the tags. So as a result what is now selected isn't the original selected text.

Here is the code for the textarea stuff as it is now:

```
$('div[id*="custom_button"]').click(function () {
    var start = textarea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textarea[0].selectionEnd;
    var replacement = '[stuff]' + textarea.val().substring(start, end) + '[/stuff]';
    textarea.val(textarea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textarea.val().substring(end, textarea.val().length));
    textarea.focus()
});
```

I was thinking of somehow getting the selected text, then finding it after adding tags, and finally re-selecting it... is that at all possible? Is there some simple solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line before `textarea.focus()`:

```
textarea.selectionEnd = (replacement.length)+end;
```